# Is it possible to create a ‘user account’ windows application without ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I am relatively new to C# and currently working on an 'Account' windows application. I did not use ASP.NET, just Winforms and a .mdf database. My main goal now is for the details of a user (from the database) to be displayed on the Home page right after I login.

For example:

**Login Page**

Username : sandy@mail.com

Password : 1234

**Home Page**

Welcome, Sandy Smith!

Your current address : Woodlands Drive

---

Here is the code for my Login button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sit\Desktop\25June_LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonAnalysis.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from TBL_LOGIN where STAFF_EMAIL ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and PASSWORD='" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            Home_Page hp = new Home_Page();
            hp.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please a valid email and password.", "alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help. Thanks!

Comment: asp.net and winforms are mutually exclusive. If you want a desktop app use windows forms else if you want web app you will go with asp.net

Comment: Help with what? Is something broken? Doesn't work as expected? There are countless good examples of creating ASP.NET pages with a login system that displays your name. Have you tried following any?

Answer (score -1):

This is how i am doing it with `winforms`

In database create table `USERS` with columns `USERID`, `PASS`, `DISPLAY_NAME`, `EMAIL`, `ANYTHING YOU WANT TO STORE FOR EACH USER`....

Create new class (`.cs file`) and name it `CurrentUser`

Inside it create `public static vars` - Datatype which is accessible from anywhere in code (write/read) - for each column in database.

So class would look like this:

```
public class CurrentUser
{
    public static int userId;
    public static string pass;
    public static string displayName;
    public static string email;
    //every other column you added
}
```

Now create login code like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sit\Desktop\25June_LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonAnalysis.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PASS, USERID, DISPLAY_NAME, FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = @MAIL", conn)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAIL", textBox1.Text);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader():

            if(dr.Read()) //We do IF since we only need first one
            {
                //Now we check if typed password is equal to password from database
                if(dr[0].ToString().Equals(textBox2.Text))
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Home_Page hp = new Home_Page();
                    hp.Show();


                    //Here we store current user data
                    CurrentUser.userId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
                    CurrentUser.pass = dr[0].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.displayName = dr[2].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.email = textBox1.Text;
                }
                else //Passwords doesn't match
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong password. Try again");
                }
            }
            else //If it hasn't found anyone with that email that mean email is incorect
            {
                MessageBox.Show("E-mail doesn't exist!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now in whatever class/form you are (which is inside your namespace) you can access current user's data with let's say `string displayName = CurrentUser.displayName`.

Or if you want to set label with hello message you can do

`label1.Text = "Welcome, " + CurrentUser.displayName + "!";`

Or better

`label1.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", CurrentUser.displayName);`

Or if you want to display messageBox with all data just do

```
string[] msg = {
String.Format("Welcome, {0}.", CurrentUser.displayName),
String.Format("Your ID is: {0} while your e-mail is {1}!", CurrentUser.userId, CurrentUser.email)
};

MessageBox.Show(String.Joing(Environment.NewLine, msg));
```

Comment: You're storing passwords in plaintext in the database. That's a security issue. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted. Then you compare hashed forms of the passwords to determine validity.

Comment: Hey everything works but the "CurrentUser.displayName = dr["STAFF_NAME"].ToString();" bit. I can't get it to appear on a label in the next form. The data type of "STAFF_NAME" in the database is varchar(200)

Comment: Could it be where I placed the CurrentUser class? Or maybe the variable types in it have to change?

Comment: @siberiangold What error it displays? Have you tried debugging and see if it stores value (in logging code)

Comment: @mason I know it is problem and I really use self made crypter/decrypter but he is just starting and password storing is question for itself but I didn't want to expand answer more so he will get to that point eventually.

Comment: @AleksaRistic There is no error. I don't think it stored any value. I can't get them to be displayed on a label once I log in... could it be the data type in my database?

Comment: Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx). Set breakpoint at your login code where you store value and after breakpoint hit check in `autos` if that var have value. If it has then problem is not in storing but displaying it. Otherwise problem is in storing and we can proceed with problem

Comment: @AleksaRistic Alright I just checked. In CurrentUser.displayName and CurrentUser.email, the values are null.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your table structure?